# how to do sum of values between excel Cells using apache poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi

i want to do sum of the values between two cells of a row using **apache poi**

i found answer for it as follows..

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(3);
Cell cell = row.createCell(4);
cell.setCellFormula("SUM(D2:D10)");
```

i won't have `D2:D10` i will have cell position like from `cell-1 to cell-5`

i want to do sum of the values between `cell-1 to cell-5`

how can i do this , please help me.

thank you.

Comment: Use [CellReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html) to turn your cells into formula-style refs?

Comment: i ttried `static String buildCellReference( int zeroBasedRow, int zeroBasedCol ) {
  CellReference cr = new CellReference(zeroBasedRow, zeroBasedCol);
  return cr.formatAsString();
 }
  but it returns `$E$51` like this how can i write formula with it?

Comment: Run it twice, once for each end of the range, then add those together to make the formula and evaluate!

Comment: Or use AreaReference with first and last cell CellReference args https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/AreaReference.html